# Navigation Bar Customization Properties Conflicting Swift (Xcode 6)

Tags: xcode, swift, fonts, colors

I am trying to edit a navigation bar to have white text and also have 'Chalkduster' font at size 20. My current code only follows through with whatever line is written last - how do I combine both of these to get the color and the font?

Code:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 15)!]
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the attributes in one dictionary and pass it:

```
let attributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 15)!,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()
]

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes
```